# Search box alignment in Chrome/FF vs. IE8

Tags: javascript, css

I have a search box, on a page. On Chrome/Safari/FF etc the box is correctly positioned on the right of the main div. The page in question is here:

http://property.begbies-traynor.com

The box in question is the Search Box on the main search, just underneath the banner.

I have tried various float techniques, clearing divs but for some reason everything I try makes no difference and on IE8 it just sits on the top of the 'Type' box.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Wayners, the link you provided does not work, could you check it is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an inline style `float:right` to the search button.

It's getting a `float:left` rule from your `.left` class

Comment: Thank you Duane, works nice I just need to restyle a few elements now.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see without a link but you should have a look on Google for how IE handles the box model differently to other browsers. I'm guessing the width of the box may be different and this has pushed it out of the container.

Again can't help without further code mate.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

As @Rick Donohoe already mentioned, without a link it's hard to see.

But what I thought about is, to have the container (like `<div id="header"></div>`) `position: relative` and having then the search-container `position: absolute`... like that:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
}

#search {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; /* push search onto the right */
    top: 0;
}
```

To avoid other browsers to read that particular css-code, you can use conditional comments for IE:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Or maybe this one will work:

```
#search {
   float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It also incorrect in IE 9 too.

For `<div align="right">` add some class, write the following and remove the align atribute:

```
.someclass {
   float:right;
   overflow:hidden
}
```